# DIY security feature on socket

Tags: python, sockets

I'm making a P2P connection using Python sockets and as a little security measure I made it so that the computer sends an ID and the server reads it and either continues the program or terminates it.

Client

```
connectionID = "123456789"
m.send(connectionID.encode('utf-8'))
```

Server

```
thisID = "123456789"
while True:
    print ("Waiting for connection")
    sc, address = s.accept()
    print (address)
    connectionID = sc.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
    if connectionID == "123456789":
        print ("Connected")
        while True:
            message = sc.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
            eval(message)
    else:
        print ("Not the correct connection ID")
```

I always get `"Not the correct connection id"`

Comment: I fixed it what I did in the client code is I put a `time.sleep(1)` before it. I think it was trying to send code through the socket to quickly and parts may have been lost. So by adding the 1 sec sleep it fixed it.

Comment: much better than an arbitrary sleep time, you can wait for the socket to be writable (means it is connected) in the client before sending, using the `select` call, e.g.: `_,wd,_ = select.select([], [m.fileno()], [], timeout_in_s)`, if wd is not empty it means you can send